# what if eigenvector of 2x2 matrix after plug eigenvalue in matrix and only one parameter left?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I stuck this problem
$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 \\ 
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$
the eigenvalue is 1 
when try to find the  eigen vector I found

$\begin{bmatrix}
1-1 & 2 \\ 
0 & 1-1
\end{bmatrix}$

$\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 2 \\ 
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$
or $2x_{2}=0$
or $ x_{2}=0$
the eigenvector might be in this form

x

0

(I try to write eigenvector by Latex by always get error -*-)

what is the vaule for $x$? because no $x$ left after I plug in eigenvalue in matrix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every $x\in\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}$, the vector

$$\begin{bmatrix}x\\0\end{bmatrix}$$

is an eigenvector of the matrix

$$\begin{bmatrix}1&2\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: thank you for help ^ ^

Answer (score 1):

If $\vec v$ is an eigenvector corresponding to an eigenvalue $\lambda$, then so is any other non-zero scalar multiply of $\vec v$. So for any $x \ne 0$,$$\begin{bmatrix}x\\0\end{bmatrix}$$
is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $1$ of this matrix. If you only need one, you usually pick an easy one such as:
$$\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: thank you for help ^ ^